# insert photo path in db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, plupload

I have database like this:

[image]

and i have textboxes what is use of to write values in my database. Everything goes OK except Photo. I want to write the path of my pictures which is uploaded using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).

I can retrieve photos from db if I'll insert its path like this: "~/Uploads/1.jpg", but while I'm uploading this files i can't write its name in database.

Here's my code which using i'm uploading photos:

```
<div id="container">
            <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a>
            <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        browse_button: 'pickfiles',
        container: document.getElementById('container'),
        url: '/Admin/Upload',
        flash_swf_url: 'Scripts/Moxie.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url: 'Scripts/Moxie.xap',

        filters: {
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            mime_types: [
                { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
                { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
            ]
        },

        init: {
            PostInit: function () {
                document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function () {
                    uploader.start();
                    return false;
                };
            },


            UploadProgress: function (up, file) {

                alert("File has succesfully added");
            },

            Error: function (up, err) {
                alert("\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message);
            }
        }
    });

    uploader.init();

</script>
```

here's my add action which using i'm inserting values in DB:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add
        (
        string Name, string Company, int Age, string Position, string Quote, string Biography,
        string Type, string Industry, string Founders, string AreaServed, string Products, 
        string WebPage, string Facebook, int PhoneNumber, string Email, string Photo
        )
    {


        Biography BioDb = new Biography();
        BioDb.Name = Name;
        BioDb.Company = Company;
        BioDb.Age = Age;
        BioDb.Position = Position;
        BioDb.Quote = Quote;
        BioDb.Biography1 = Biography;
        BioDb.Type = Type;
        BioDb.Industry = Industry;
        BioDb.Founders = Founders;
        BioDb.AreaServed = AreaServed;
        BioDb.Products = Products;
        BioDb.WebPage = WebPage;
        BioDb.Facebook = Facebook;
        BioDb.Phone = PhoneNumber;
        BioDb.Email = Email;
        BioDb.Photo = "~/Uploads/" + Photo;

        BIOEntities bio = new BIOEntities();

        bio.Biographies.AddObject(BioDb);
        bio.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

**But** when I'm debugging it Photo is **null** and in db is inserted only ~/Uploads/ (which is name of the folder). I want to insert in db ~/Uploads/ + the name of the photo which is uploaded by user.

anyone can tell me how can I do that?

**thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will need this:

I have added textbox for photo's name:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Photo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo)
        </div>
```

and this in upload:

```
 UploadProgress: function (up, file) {
                _file_name = file.name;
               $('#Photo').val(_file_name);

            }
```

everything works well.

Thanks